# Assignment: Adding image link to first web page

Tags: image, hyperlink

Long story short, I have a teacher in college who doesn't answer questions and I'm currently being taught as a first time html coder online, without sound. He basically points to code on the screen and doesn't answer questions and then logs off. I need help, please. I have an assignment due on Tuesday.

I have to add an the following image link (and 4 more,) to my first web page.

http://www.mrpettit.net/2010/web1/5.png

How do I fix the first example to add that image of the Batman logo please? I've tried a few things and it didn't work out.

Thanks so much!

Comment: This is what I have so far (with the html.goodies as an example) but I still can't get it to show up properly. :(

Comment: You should provide the code you wrote when you are asking a question!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My image links</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.mrpettit.net/2010/web1/5.png"><img src="http://www.mrpettit.net/2010/web1/5.png"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. The think I didn't understand is that the assignment said to use 4 photo links (given to us) from files in our computer. So - can I link it from my own folder? I don't get that at all.

Comment: just copy the photo to the same folder as your html page and replace *http://www.mrpettit.net/2010/web1/5.png* with that photo's name.